# Teams detecting message edit

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I'm currently making a teams bot and I want to generate some content based off of a user's message and this is proving to be rather difficult.

What I want to happen is when they post something to a teams chat is for my bot to respond appropriately, compiling their code for example, which is currently working correctly. However, if they've made an error in their code, then I want them to be able to edit their message and for the bot to recompile.

The code situation is merely an example, I know it's not a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, bot does not receive an event when a message is edited. This is a known issue. We have an active item on it which we are working on. But we cannot give you a firm timeline on when this will be available.

Comment: Ok, thank you, is there a way I can read a specific message again if the user, say, clicks a button on an adaptive card?

Comment: Could you please help me understand what do you mean by read a message again? Do you want the bot to be notified when a user clicks on button?

Comment: When the user clicks on a button I want to open a task module and re-read the content that they previously sent just in case it has changed. I couldn't find anything specific in the MS Docs other than the Graph API but that requires access to all messages.. im not sure

Comment: That's not possible without  Graph  APIs. You could try maintaining the details at backend and show it in task module.

Comment: @GousiaBegum is there link to this "active item" where we can follow the progress? Would it be possible to build such a functionality for a custom adapter or is it rather a limitation of the bot framework?